# Put a UIButton inside a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to put a `UIButton` inside a `UITableViewCell`.

The `UITableView` also has cells containing `UILabels` and and the cells have gradient backgrounds being drawn into them. The problem I am seeing is that my `UIButton` is just a filled black cell with no text display, and changing both the color and background color properties does not appear to do anything.

Here's the code I use to  create the button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"InAppViewController, doing this - width= %f", self.wdth);
    static NSString *ProductTableIdentifier = @"ProductTableIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ProductTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        if (self.wdth >= 700) {
            CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (self.wdth - 100), 40);
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame reuseIdentifier: ProductTableIdentifier] autorelease];

            // Set up some labels...

            CGRect seenValueRect = CGRectMake(self.wdth-320, 0, 100, 40);
            UIButton *seenValue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [seenValue setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            seenValue.tag = kSeenValueTag;
            seenValue.frame = seenValueRect;
            [seenValue setTitle:@"I'm a clone" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:seenValue];

            [seenValue release];

            // Continue setting up cell...
```

The pastebin link contains the code to the entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` function (for the `UITableView` in question).

http://pastebin.com/bpEyfruE

Comment: Take a look at the *Customizing Cells* section in the iOS `UITableView` documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that you're releasing the UIButton innitialized with convenience initializer `[UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)]`. Try removing the `[button release]`

Answer (score 0):

It can't even be that you have to do `[cell addSubview:seenValue];` instead of `[cell.contentView addSubview:seenValue];`

You could also try to do `CGRectMake(110, 11, 185, 30)` instead of `CGRectMake(self.wdth-320, 0, 100, 40)`: I use it and it works well but I don't know if it what you need